# Capturing installed applications with MDT

Tags: windows, deployment, wds, imaging, mdt

I am using Microsoft Deployment Workbench v6.3.8450.1000.

I am trying to configure MDT to capture/deploy Windows 10 images. I have done a few test runs and I am able to capture the image with LiteTouch.vbs and deploy it with PXE boot, as expected.

However none of the applications I installed into the base image are being deployed. The image I have captured had a bunch of software installed. When I capture an image from this computer and deploy it onto a different computer none of the pre-installed applications from the imaged machine are installed.

To prepare a system for image capture I install Windows normally, then enter Audit Mode with Ctrl+Shift+F3. Then I install all my applications and reboot with the "Generalize" option selected. Then on reboot I run LiteTouch.vbs and capture the image.

I've got to be missing something. How do you ensure that the MDT image capture encompasses pre-installed applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my own problem.

I had forgotten to import the captured image from the \Captures folder into the \Operating Systems folder. Once that was done I had to modify the Install Image contained in the Task Sequence under "Install"->"Install Operating System"->"Operating system to install" to point at the captured .wim file.

Someone else also taught me that MDT is typically done in a more hierarchical manner than what I am attempting. What I am trying to do is basically deploy a barebones image, modify that image, and rewrite the original barebones image with the modified one all on the same deployment share.

What I *should* be doing instead is creating a barebones deployment image on a deployment share. Then modify the barebones image and capture it under a new deployment share.

Comment: Since it's just image modification and capture, you could almost do it woth pure WDS. no need for MDT. MDT allows you to modularize  your deployment without having to capture it repeatedly every time you have a change and also reduces the need for multiple images supporting different hardware platforms. You can have a single image that supports all of your hardware platforms. I personally avoid image capture as it makes un-manageable/bloated/broken images quickly.

Comment: WDS has a native image capture system so you don't need to use toolkits.